# How to complie dynamic html using cons.underscore?

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

I have converted static html and converted it into strings and emailed it. Now want to pass dynamic value to the html and convert it into string and email it. I'm using cons.underscore as view engine for rendering html pages.

Comment: Solved above by following:
var u = require('underscore);
var contents = fs.readFileSync(filepath).toString();
var tplcontents = u.template(contents, { email: email });  // compile

Answer (score 0):

DON'T USE readFileSync! It will lock your program!

If you need pass dynamic variables into template render, you need use the .render in your express server.

Maybe you will need install the extensions:

```
npm install underscore --save
npm install consolidate --save
```

For this, set your template engine in express:

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', require('consolidate').underscore);
```

And get the page like this on your listener:

```
var options = { email : 'test@op.com'};
res.render('index', options);
```